# 2001 Saab 9-5 Air Conditioner Fan (upper vents) not working

Tags: ac, saab, 9-5, vents

2001 Saab 9-5 Wagon 9-5 Air Conditioner (upper vents) Fan stopped working.

I've examined the DICE fuses, but they all seem to be good.

What should I be checking next?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about Saab, but BMWs have a blowout resistor that controls the fan speed. The telltale that the resistor went bad is erratic/inoperative fan behavior.